# Slide out drawer poor FPS on mobile

Tags: css, angularjs, performance

I have a drawer menu on my application that runs great on desktop but on any mobile device I see an ugly jank.

In the header I have a boolean value that gets set to true/false on click of the hamburger which will add `out` class to the `.container` sliding it out. The drawer is absolute to the page positioned to the top right and when the out class is on the container, it moves 280px to the right exposing the drawer.

here is the html and css simplified:

```
<div class="landing-page-container" ng-class="isMenuOut ? 'out' : ''">
<header/>
<main/>
<footer/>
</div>

<sidebar>
```

css:

```
.home-slide-menu{
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.landing-page-container{
  right:0;
  position: relative;
  transition: right 0.2s ease-in 0s;
}

.landing-page-container.out{
  right:280px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This may not be enough to help debug this but if there are any redflags please let me know and if you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 3D transforms.

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_movement_smoothly_using_css.htm

> When dealing with displaying things on the screen, the calculations behind it all can be done either by the CPU or the GPU (aka graphics card). In general, you should rely on your GPU as much as you can for any display-related tasks...especially for tasks such as animation.
>
> How do you ensure your animations run in hardware mode on the GPU? By
>   using translate3d! When you transform an element using translate3d,
>   that element is in GPU country in Webkit-based browsers like Chrome
>   and Safari (which is what your iPhone and iPad use).

Here is a simple example I made:

https://jsfiddle.net/asmsomtw/

**Important CSS Snippet from fiddle**

```
/* Transition effect and timing */
div {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
    transition: transform 500ms ease-in;
}

/* The transform applied by appended class that toggles drawer to hide */
.hide {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
```

Try it out on the devices you are having jank issues with and then swap those values to be `right` like your original implementation and see if you can see the difference.

Never abuse the GPU though, be selective about what you hardware accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a 2d transform, it should be more fluid

```
-ms-transform: translate(-280px,0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate(-280px,0); /* Safari */
transform: translate(-280px,0); /* Standard syntax */
```

Comment: This actually made it perform worst. It went from just around 40fps to 25fps

Comment: You want to use 3d transforms, not 2d. This makes sure your devices uses hardware acceleration and pushed them into the GPU.

Comment: How do I use 3d transforms?

Comment: I think 3d transforms definitely yields a performance increase on a desktop, but I'm not sure if would make a huge difference on mobile.

Comment: 3d transforms make a huge difference on mobile devices!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using TweenMax. It's a JS animation library that works well with Angular and prioritizes performance. You can check it out here:

http://greensock.com/

Even Google recommends it:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/animations/css-vs-javascript?hl=en

For example, here's how you would do what you're doing in TweenMax in Angular

```
function(){
    TweenMax.to(someDomElementAsVariable, 0.3, {
        right:"350px"
    });
};
```

That function will change the 'right' value of someDomElementAsVariable to 350px over the course of 0.3 seconds.